# When is the word "ever" being used?

Tags: word-usage

I am worried about the usage of the word "ever".

For example if I'd like to say:

> "Increasing fires in the rain forest pose an **ever** greater threat to the livelihoods, the economy and health of the indigenous people."

Is the word "ever" here right in place or do I need to use "even" ?

Best and thanks for all the help!

Comment: "Ever" would mean that the threat grows with time, "even" would mean that the threat is greater than some other (previously mentioned) threat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Ever" and "even" are both possible, depending on what you are trying to say.

An ever greater threat is one that continuously increases.

An even greater threat is one that is emphatically greater than the one being discussed.

[Ever (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ever)

[Even (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/even)